# During object to primitive conversion why does the 'hint' change depending on the presence of obj.toString()/obj.valueOf()?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, hint

As far as I know, in JavaScript during object to primitive conversion, there are three variants of type conversion called "hints", being: string, number and default. And in case of binary + operator the "default" hint is used which results in a "number" conversion.
It looks like the hint changes depending on the presence or absence of properties `[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)`, `toString()`, `valueOf()`, is it true?

In this code it behaves like I expect it - since there is a binary + the hint is "default" and
the conversion result is "number". It behaves the  same way if at least one of the properties `([Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)/ toString()/ valueOf()` is present.

```js
let obj = {

    [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
        alert(`hint: ${hint}`); // shows hint: default
    },

    toString() {},
    valueOf() {},

};
alert(obj + 1); // shows Nan if any of the above properties are present
alert(typeof(obj + 1)); // shows number if any of the above properties are present
```

In this second code, there are none of those properties and the result shows as string (as if by string concatenation).

```js
let obj = {};
alert(obj + 1);            // [object Object]1
alert(typeof(obj + 1));    // shows string
```

Can someone please explain me the reason of this difference in behavior?

Comment: It's not exactly light reading, but the language spec describes all this in intricate detail.

Comment: "*the hint changes depending on the presence or absence of method*" - no, you've got it the wrong way round. The hint comes first (depending on whether the object is coerced to a number or to a string), and it decides which methods to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently in the second case `Object.prototype.valueOf()` is indeed gets called because the `hint` is indeed `default`, but as stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

> base implementation of `Object.prototype.valueOf()` is deliberately
> useless: by returning an object, its return value will never be used
> by any primitive conversion algorithm.

And so the next in line method is called -  `toString()`, hence the result of case two shows `string`

And as for the first case `alert(obj + 1)` shows `NaN` because the return of `toString()` is `undefined`. And in the same manner `typeof(obj + 1)` shows `number` because `typeof(NaN) === 'number'`. I missed that one.